# Get Instagram video views with Graph API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, video, metrics

I'm using the API Graph for Facebook and Instagram to get metrics from my video's posts.
I have no problem using this API for Facebook, but on Instagram I can't access all the information I need to make good data analysis.
For example, I can't access a retention graph, segmentation of viewers age & gender etc. on my Instagram videos. In addition, some data is available in the app, but I don't succeed to get it with API (aggregation of viewers age and gender).
My first need is to get video's views exact number. When I get the metric with "video_views" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights/) stop the views count when we make ads.

Is there another method I should use to get my data / Best pratcices? Do I need to use other API for videos views / other video insight like retention graph?
Do not hesitate to answer me even to give me leads since I am a beginner, and thank you for everything.